# How is numpy.choice different from numpy.randint?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to sample with replacement from an array A of length n. I want to know how the below two commands are different. If they both give the same result which one is better (in terms of performance etc...)

```
A[np.random.randint(0, n, n)]

A[np.random.choice(n, n)]
```

Comment: Have you tried timing them?

Comment: Usually Choice seems faster for n = 1 million, but in some of the trials, choice took slightly longer

Comment: In my quick time tests, they were about the same for large `n`, while `choice` took longer for small `n`.  They probably both use the same random number generator, but `choice` has a longer setup time - after all it accepts more parameters.  But the code for both is compiled, which is hard to study.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of choice is to sample an array, giving it an integer is a shortcut to giving it a range of that integer's length. So randint is likely going to be more efficient if you're misusing choice the way you are.

However the correct way to do it is `np.random.choice(A, size=n)`. That's exactly how you spell "sample with replacement".

Answer (score 1):

`randint` returns a random integer in the provided range.
`choice` returns a random element from a provided array, or if you provide an int (like u did) it functions like `np.random.randint(0, n, n)`.
So, in this example there's no difference however I imagine `randint` would be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Both numpy.randon.randint and numpy.random.choice gives you an option to select random numbers either from a range(in case of randint) or from an array(in case of choice). When your array has items in a range, then The main difference of using numpy.random.choice is to:

- Specify if you want the outcomes with or without replacement from the array.
- Specify the probabilities associated with each entry in the array.

> outcome of one coin flip
>
> - `np.random.randint(2)`

> outcomes of ten thousand coin flips
>
> - `np.random.randint(2, size=10000)`

> outcome of one coin flip
>
> - `np.random.choice([0, 1])`

> outcome of ten thousand coin flips
>
> - `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10000)`

> outcomes of ten thousand biased coin flips
>
> - `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10000, p=[0.8, 0.2])`